# PUT does not insert object in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, http-put

I'm having a problem with Web API where I want to create a new object in SQL Server.
The PUT method is used to update an expensenote. An expensenote contains dailyexpensenotes. A dailyexpensenote contains individualexpenses.

In the GUI, a user that edits his expensenote can:

1. Fill in an empty individualexpense with value > 0 (Creates a new individualexpense)
2. Change an existing individualexpense (Updates the existing individualexpense)
3. Clear an individualexpense/change value to 0 (Deletes the existing individualexpense)

After this the user clicks save and the entire expensenote is sent by ajax call to the web service. Nr 2 and Nr 3 are working as desired but the Nr 1 doesn't work and gives no error.

PUT method

```
// PUT api/expenses/5
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Expensenote exUpdate)
{
    expensenote ex = (from e in db.expensenotes
                      where e.ID == id
                      select e).FirstOrDefault();
    if (ex == null)
    {
        //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Request was not found.");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Expensenotedaily d in exUpdate.dailyExpenses)
        {
            var daily = ex.expensenotedailies.SingleOrDefault(da => da.ID == d.ID);

            daily.city = d.city;
            daily.dailyallowance = d.dailyallowance;

            foreach (Expenseindividual i in d.individualExpenses)
            {
                expenseindividual individual = daily.expenseindividuals.SingleOrDefault(ind => ind.ID == i.ID);
                if (i.value == 0)
                {
                    if (!(individual == null))
                    {
                        db.expenseindividuals.Remove(individual);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!(individual == null))
                    {
                        individual.value = i.value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        expenseindividual newInd = db.expenseindividuals.Create();
                        newInd.typecode_ID = i.expensetypeID;
                        newInd.daily_ID = daily.ID;
                        newInd.typecode = db.typecodes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.ID == i.expensetypeID);
                        newInd.expensenotedaily = daily;
                        newInd.value = i.value;
                        newInd.creditcard = false;
                        db.expenseindividuals.Add(newInd);
                        //SOLUTION: db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

expenseindividual datamodel class

```
public partial class expenseindividual
{
    public expenseindividual()
    {
        this.supplementalinfoes = new HashSet<supplementalinfo>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
    public bool creditcard { get; set; }
    public int daily_ID { get; set; }
    public int typecode_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual expensenotedaily expensenotedaily { get; set; }
    public virtual typecode typecode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<supplementalinfo> supplementalinfoes { get; set; }
}
```

When I debug I see that all attributes are passed correctly.
Using newInd = new expenseindividual() instead of Create() doesn't fix the problem.
I tried setting the expenseindividual.ID manually and this makes the insert work but it must auto increment and auto increment is enabled.
So I'm really wondering what causes the problem here and how I can fix it?

Comment: When a new expenseindividual in created in the loop this has an ID=0 before db.SaveChanges(). This means that following iterations will find this existing object instead of creating a new one because of expenseindividuals.SingleOrDefault(ind => ind.ID == i.ID).
I solved this by adding db.SaveChanges(); after db.expenseindividuals.Add(newInd);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to insert a new expense note into the database when one does not already exist?

Firstly... this code currently ignores expense notes that do not already exist in the database...

```
expensenote ex = (from e in db.expensenotes
                              where e.ID == id
                              select e).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ex == null)
            {
                //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Request was not found.");
            }
            else
            {
```

`ex` will always be null when you pass an id of an expense note that does not already exist inside of the database, therefore no code will be run.

The convention is that typically **PUT** is always used to **update** a record, **POST** is used instead when trying to create one but thats up to you.

You need to implement your logic to create a new record within the if statement, replacing the commented out return statement.

Comment: ex is the expensenote, normally this will never be null, the expensenote ex is accessed in the application and afterwards saved, the ID remains unchanged. 
My problem occurs when trying to update an individual expense (expenseindividual) and this should happen in the last 'else' before db.SaveChanges

Comment: In that case your question baffles me, it explains an entirely different problem altogether.

Comment: Basically the problem comes down to the method not inserting an object (expenseindividual) with id=0 in a table with auto increment. Providing the object with an ID that doesnt yet exist makes it work which proves that the rest of the code is correct.

Comment: I found the solution and commented it on my question.